# Laravel Passport Personal Access Tokens is not "personal" at all

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

I followed this guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport and i successed create secret keys. However, when i login as other users, i can see the keys that i created from admin accounts. i.e:

**admin**: personal key string is also "ABCDE"
**user A** : personal key string is also "ABCDE"
**user B**: personal key string is also "ABCDE"

It looks like the "ABCDE" is global? Any clues why i get this error?

Comment: Here are the steps i am doing:

1. Login as admin

2. Edit admin and add personal-access-tokens

3. Admin has 1 token now. 

4. Edit User_A. But here i can see the same token that i just created for admin. I haven't create any new tokens for User_A.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says:

> When deploying Passport to your production servers for the first time, you will likely need to run the  passport:keys command. This
>   command generates the encryption keys Passport needs in order to
>   generate access token. The generated keys are not typically kept in
>   source control:

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

I'm pretty sure your forgot or had no permission on the folder to persist them to disk

Comment: Nope, still same issue. OK, will edit the topic to make it easier to understand